# How to shorten A LOT of IF statements in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm doing some data filtering for each table in the database, and this database has 567 tables

so here is my filter for 1 table [Source]

```
 if (Context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains("Source"))
                    AccessControlRule("SourceID",
                        "select SourceID from Source where IsDelete = 0",
                        AccessPermission.Allow);
         else
            AccessControlRule("SourceID",
                        "select SourceID from Source where IsDelete = 1 OR IsDelete = null",
                        AccessPermission.Allow);
```

The snippet above filters **Sources**. now I'm currently writing IF statements for ALL tables, which means there's a lot of code & (copy/paste) and I'm afraid this could lead to a lot of human errors.

Do you have a way to shorten this? perhaps a loop type of process?

Thanks!

Comment: OT first you do a ToLower(), then you check against "Source" (with Capital S)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've not *really* given enough information, but i'll bite... 
Assuming all your tables/code follows that same pattern, its fairly simple:

```
// You'll want to whitelist the tables, so you are not
// trusting user input for the table name
var tables = new List<String>() { "Source", ... };

foreach(var table in tables){
    if (Context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains(table)){
        AccessControlRule(
           $"{table}ID",
            "select {table}ID from {table} where IsDelete = 0", 
            AccessPermission.Allow
        );
    } else {
        AccessControlRule(
           $"{table}ID", 
            "select {table}ID from {table} where IsDelete = 1 OR IsDelete = null",
            AccessPermission.Allow
        );
    }
}
```

BUT - you probably don't want to actually configure anything like AccessRules or Security using the Referrer value, as it can be trivially spoofed... You are not relying on this code for some form of security are you?

---

Edit if your keys are different you can just use a map of tablename -> keyname (via a Dictionary is probably easiest) instead of the list:

```
// You'll want to whitelist the tables, so you are not
// trusting user input for the table name
var tables = new Dictionary<String, String>() { 
   {"Source", "SourceId" },
   ... 
};

foreach(var table in tables){
    if (Context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains(table.Key)){
        AccessControlRule(
           $"{table.Value}",
            "select {table.Value} from {table.Key} where IsDelete = 0", 
            AccessPermission.Allow
        );
    } else {
        AccessControlRule(
           $"{table.Value}", 
            "select {table.Value} from {table.Key} where IsDelete = 1 OR IsDelete = null",
            AccessPermission.Allow
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shark! apologies for not including all details.. but you're definitely right!! let me give this a go

Comment: I'm using C# version 6 so Interpolated string $"{table}ID" is not available in C# 5, do you have any other alternative?

Comment: ... Yes you can just join the strings i,e, (table + "ID"), or use String.Format("{0}ID", table). Why are you only using that version? Just upgrade, it doesn't have any issues with compatibility...

Comment: Cannot reiterate enough that if you don't have something like a table whitelist this is very dangerous for SQL Injection

Comment: @Milney thanks for your answer, one more concern, your answer assumes the table name is called Source and the PK is called SourceID...
what if the Source PK is named ssID?  note: I can list array all tables PK and table name

Comment: @Ryanman you're right in my case the table name is different from the PK name.. but ends with ..ID e.i abcID

Comment: @Yoshuwa - See my edit. You just need to loop through pairs of tablename+keyname instead of the single list of table names

Comment: @Milney I got again an issue with my C# version using  $"{table.Value}"...  so I used String.Format(table.Value) instead nad it's not working.. any C# 5 equivalent?

Comment: I'm using this to filter records (soft delete)

Comment: @Yoshuwa - If you are not adding "ID" to the end, you don't need the String.Format... Just use table.Value instead of String.Format(table.Value)

Comment: @Milney Got it! Thanks again!